# Equivalent to InvokeRequired in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Is there an equivalent to Form.InvokeRequired in WPF, e.g. Dispatcher.InvokeRequired?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is slightly odd as  it doesn't appear in intellisense, but you can use:

```
var dispatcher = myDispatcherObject.Dispatcher;
if (dispatcher.CheckAccess()) { /* ... */ }
```

As all UI components inherit from `DispatcherObject` this should solve your specific problem, but it is not specific to the UI thread - it can be used for any dispatcher.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent is [Dispatcher.CheckAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution that came to mind is:

```
if ( Dispatcher.Thread.Equals( Thread.CurrentThread ) )
{
    Action( );
}
else
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke( Action );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a Windows Store app, the above example won't work. Here's an example that *does* work. Modify as needed, of course :)

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates the UI after the albums have been retrieved. This prevents the annoying delay when receiving the albums list.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="albums"></param>
public void UpdateUiAfterAlbumsRetrieved(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<PhotoAlbum> albums)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
    {
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            ddlAlbums.DataContext = albums;
            ddlAlbums.IsEnabled = true;
            tbxProgress.Text = String.Empty;
            ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            ProgressBar.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        ddlAlbums.DataContext = albums;
        ddlAlbums.IsEnabled = true;
        tbxProgress.Text = String.Empty;
        ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
    }
}
```