# How can I use InvokeRequired in WPF?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I'm working in a WPF (c#) application and need to use thread in some process. but "InvokeRequired" dont work.
I look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765243/equivalent-to-invokerequired-in-wpf) but I cant get work.

This is my code:

```
private void CambiarProgreso(string texto, int valor)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired) //preguntamos si la llamada se hace desde un hilo 
        {
            //si es así entonces volvemos a llamar a CambiarProgreso pero esta vez a través del delegado 
            //instanciamos el delegado indicandole el método que va a ejecutar 
            CambiarProgresoDelegado delegado = new CambiarProgresoDelegado(CambiarProgreso);
            //ya que el delegado invocará a CambiarProgreso debemos indicarle los parámetros 
            object[] parametros = new object[] { texto, valor };
            //invocamos el método a través del mismo contexto del formulario (this) y enviamos los parámetros 
            this.Invoke(delegado, parametros);
        }
        else
        {
            //en caso contrario, se realiza el llamado a los controles 
            lblProgreso.Content = texto;
            PrbProgreso.Value = valor;
        }
    }

  delegate void CambiarProgresoDelegado(string texto, int valor);
```

Thank you ver much!

Comment: You should use `PrbProgreso.InvokeRequired` since that is the object you like to change the value on. See here the example in `SetText` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: InvokeRequired dont exist int WPF...Thanks!

Comment: Oh, just read C#. In WPF this task is easier by using `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` and `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Side node: The way u use a delegate at the moment, you'll end up with multiple delegates of the same method signature. just name it `delegate void delegateStringIntArg` or something the like. Easier to reuse.

Comment: @dognose: +1, just remember `Dispatcher` is the shorthand for dispatcher of the current thread that you are in. So using `Application.Current.Dispatcher` is probably what you want, if you are trying to update the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

This resolve my problem. 
Thanks.

```
private void CambiarProgreso(string texto, int valor)
        {
            if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) //preguntamos si la llamada se hace desde un hilo 
            {
                //si es así entonces volvemos a llamar a CambiarProgreso pero esta vez a través del delegado 
                //instanciamos el delegado indicandole el método que va a ejecutar 
                //CambiarProgresoDelegado delegado = new CambiarProgresoDelegado(CambiarProgreso);
                //ya que el delegado invocará a CambiarProgreso debemos indicarle los parámetros 
                object[] parametros = new object[] { texto, valor };
                //invocamos el método a través del mismo contexto del formulario (this) y enviamos los parámetros 
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new CambiarProgresoDelegado(CambiarProgreso), parametros);
            }
            else
            {
                //en caso contrario, se realiza el llamado a los controles 
                lblProgreso.Content = texto;
                PrbProgreso.Value = valor;
            }
        }
```